# How to get around using a reverse_iterator within a constexpr function

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, constexpr, const-iterator

I have a prepopulated `std::vector<uint64_t>` that I am passing to my `constexpr` function by constant reference and another `std::vector<uint64_t>` that I'm passing by reference to be populated with values.

I want to calculate the distance between each element in the `collection` vector below and store the results into the `distances` vector. In other words, I want to take the value at index 1 and subtract it from the value at index 0 then store that into the other vector, and so on.

I was thinking of using either `reverse_iterator` or `const_reverse_iterator` to help with this process...

```
constexpr void euclidean_distance(const std::vector<uint64_t>& collection, std::vector<uint64_t> distances ) {
    auto It1 = collection.rbegin();   // fails to compile
    auto It2 = collection.crbegin();  // fails to compile

    // ... code to do the calculation...
}
```

However, within Visual Studio 2017 both of these fail to compile as they are not a literal type...

What options do I have to achieve a similar functionality?

Comment: Given the description, I don't see the need for reverse iterator.

Comment: @eerorika I think I was thinking about it too hard... I'm just so using to using `auto it = container.begin(), container.end(), etc...` that I could just do it manually via indexing...

Comment: basically: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference

Comment: @NathanOliver that sounds nice since it is `const_expr` however, that's only available for C++20... atm I'm limited to C++17...

Comment: @FrancisCugler you don't need the constexpr.  You cant create elements in it until run time so you don't need a compile time calculation.

Comment: @NathanOliver, atm I am using `vector` to keep my code simplified just to make sure I'm getting the correct values, however, when I'm done my function(s) should be all compile-time generated... The `std::vector` is a temporary thing...

Comment: Let me ask you, the data in the array/vector/container, when are you getting it?  To put it another way, when will you know the value of all the elements in the container?

Comment: @NathanOliver The container `collection` is already populated with recalculated values when it is passed to the `euclidean_distance()` function. The values that this function will calculate will be stored into `distances`.

Comment: How could you use `std::vector` in constexpr in C++17?

Answer (score 1):

There are too many issues here, and I can't tell which is the problem...

In C++, constexpr means that the value *must* be available at compile time. const, on the other hand, just means the data is unchangeable.

Don't use constexpr here. It makes no sense. In fact, even having your function return const makes no sense! void functions don't return anything, and should not be qualified by const or constexpr under any circumstances. constexpr functions are for cases where you want to evaluate computations between primitive data types (i.e. int, float, char) at compile time, and the inputs must also be constexpr.

`primes` isn't listed here, by the way...is it a typo?

You shouldn't be initializing .crend() to anything in the first place, by the way. You should use .crbegin() instead.

`const std::vector<uint64_t>&` is not a const reference, it's a reference to a const vector. And technically, all references are const...

Comment: Yes, that was a copy & past typo... I'm using the `word` collection in my question since it is a generic question, but in my actual code, I'm working with a list of prime numbers...

Comment: I thought you could use `constexpr` functions to do calculations at compile time instead of runtime? This was kind of my aim instead of resorting to template meta programming...

Comment: @FrancisCugler Note that `constexpr` means do the thing at compile time.  `vector` allocates, so it is a run time object.  You can't mix them together really.

Comment: @NathanOliver True, but what if I replaced it with `std::array`?

Comment: As for .crend() .rend() yes, they should have been .rbegin(), .crbegin() as that was a typo on my part, but still, it will fail to compile because they are not constexpr qualified.

Comment: @fvla: *"void functions don't return anything, and should not be qualified by const or constexpr"*. they could. const only apply to member functions, but if this is not mutated, `const` should be probably added. `constexpr` should be added to allow to use the function in constant expression, even if not const by itself, non-const accessors of array are now `constexpr`. (`std::vector` cannot be used in consexpr in C++17, but could be in C++20).